# What exactly is "DOM-based XSS Attacks"?

Tags: web, xss

I read from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting) that:

> **DOM-based XSS Attacks**: the payload is executed as a result of
>   modifying the DOM environment in the victim’s browser used by the
>   original client side script, so that the client side code runs in an
>   unexpected manner. That is, the page itself does not change, but the
>   client side code contained in the page executes differently due to the
>   malicious modifications that have occurred in the DOM environment.

Could anyone give an example of it? It's not as easy to picture as the `Stored XSS Attack` and `Reflected XSS Attack`.

Answer (score 1):

That text looks to be a copy of part of the [description of DOM-based XSS from the OWASP wiki](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) (or vice-versa).

Basically, the idea is that, unlike either "reflected" or "stored" XSS, the attacker doesn't actually need to get code included in the document sent back from the server, it instead takes advantage of a script that's already there and uses some property or piece of data that the attacker can change.

The example they give is of a script that calls `document.write` using part of the `document.location.href` property. Without getting the server to store or reflect anything, an attacker can get code executed on that page by putting a `<script>` into the URL.

Answer (score 1):

In DOM-based XSS, the HTTP response from the server never changes, but the client side code contained in the page executes differently due to the malicious modifications that have occurred in the DOM environment. Here's an example of a DOM-based XSS (taken from [OWASP's website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS)):

Suppose the following code is used to create a form to let the user choose his/her preferred language. A default language is also provided in the query string, as the parameter “default”.

```
Select your language:
<select><script>    
document.write("<OPTION value=1>"+document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.indexOf("default=")+8)+"</OPTION>");    
document.write("<OPTION value=2>English</OPTION>");    
</script></select>
```

The page is invoked with a URL such as:

```
http://www.some.site/page.html?default=French
```

A DOM Based XSS attack against this page can be accomplished by sending the following URL to a victim:

```
http://www.some.site/page.html?default=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

The webpage on the page (after processing the initial javascript with the `document.write`) will look like:

```
Select your language:
<select>    
<OPTION value=1><script>alert(document.cookie)</script></OPTION>
<OPTION value=2>English</OPTION>
</select>
```

---

BONUS: [Self-XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS)

Facebook came up with a [fancy name](https://www.facebook.com/help/246962205475854) for XSS scams where scammers trick users into copying and pasting malicious content into their browsers' web developer console.

Comment: How to prevent such attacks, if the URL itself modified then is there anything in the victim hands to stop such attacks proactively.